# Using entity_lookup inside an entity_generate migration process plugins

Tags: 8, migrations

I'm trying to use an entity_lookup process plugin inside an entity_generate process plugin. The YML looks like this

```
field_validation:
    plugin: entity_generate
    access_check: false
    entity_type: node
    source: validation_name
    value_key: title
    bundle: validation
    ignore_case: true
    values:
      title: validation_name
      body: validation_description
      field_validation_type:
        plugin: entity_lookup
          access_check: false
          ignore_case: true
          source: validation_type
```

The error I'm getting is

> Uncaught PHP Exception
>   Drupal\Core\Config\UnsupportedDataTypeConfigException: "Invalid
>   data type in config xxxxxx, found in xxxxxx : A colon cannot be used
>   in an unquoted mapping value at line 282 (near "  source:
>   validation_type")." at xxxxxx line 117, referer: xxxxxx

Because I'm relatively new in using the Migrate/Migrate Plus modules, I'm not sure if the error is triggered because I'm doing something wrong with the syntax or just because I can't use entity_lookup inside an entity_generate. So, the question is: can I do something like this, or I'm forced to use a separate migration instead of entity_generate and the call it with migration_lookup?

[later edit, just for context]

my field definition:

```
-
 name: validation_type
 label: 'Validation Type'
 selector: $.Description.Validation[*].Type #item_selector is set to $.Schema[*]
```

the relevant part of the source JSON:

```
{
  "Schema": [
    {
      "Description": {
        "Validation": [
          {
            "Type": "CUSTOM_TYPE",
            "Description": "lorem ipsum"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you actually can use entity_lookup inside entity_generate. The problem here was with the wrong indentation bellow `plugin: entity_lookup`. Yup... it was that kind of "bug" (feeling embarrassed) :)